# Why DefaultModelBinder doesn't bind route value ID from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, get, model-binding

ASP.NET MVC

In short:
I have a get action and a post action

when I type in browser localhost:port/Employee/Edit/1 I call get action, so in URL I have this whole url string. When I press submit button, in post action defaultmodelbinder doesnt bind id from URL!!!! I HAVE TO ADD HIDDEN FIELD for id. But why? I also have delete action (post), that gets id too, and I dont need to add hidden field for id. why?

More specifically:

I have the model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Int32 EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Phone { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public String Other { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 actions

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            EmployeeViewModel model;
            using (var dbSession = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                var employee = dbSession.Query<Employee>().First(e => e.EmployeeId == id && e.ExpireDate==null);
                model = new EmployeeViewModel(employee);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbSession=NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            using (var transaction=dbSession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var employee = model.ToEmployee();
                dbSession.Merge(employee);
                transaction.Commit();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

And 1 View (HERE I HAVE TO WRITE THIS LINE @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId) )

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Other, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Other, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Other, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

Comment: Because the parameter in the method is named `id` and the property in your model is named `EmployeeId` They are not the same. And if you change the model property to `Id` it will be bound

Comment: oh, my god, thank you. so stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

> Because the parameter in the method is named id and the property in
>   your model is named EmployeeId They are not the same. And if you
>   change the model property to Id it will be bound

Thanks, Stephen Muecke

Comment: Why you copy paste message from Stephen ?